# Unable to use java code in scala

Tags: java, scala

The following scala file is located in a folder that also contains subfolder de\tilman\mathParser. In that subfolder the java class MathMLParser is located.

```
import de.tilman.mathParser.MathMLParser

object MathML2LaTeX{
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    /*try {
      val parser = new MathMLParser()     
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => println("exception caught: " + e);
    } */

  }
}
```

If I try to compile:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\MathMl2Latex\MathParser> scala MathML2LaTeX.scala
C:\Users\Aage\Documents\MathMl2Latex\MathParser\MathML2LaTeX.scala:1: error: not found: object de
import de.tilman.mathParser.MathMLParser
   ^
one error found
Process scala exited with code 1
```

I'm doing this in a simple texteditor,it is a tiny program I'm writing. Just wanted to try writing something in Scala and I am thinking it shouldn't be neccessary to start project in an IDE for a small thing like this. Waiting for Netbeans to load probably increases "development" time by 50%. (just gonna call a method in MathMLParser with text in clipboard as argument and put the returned value back on clip board...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the `scala` runner isn't looking in `.` for the classpath? See `scala -help` and `scalac -help`. Try `scala -classpath . MathML2LaTeX.scala`

Also, can you confirm that `MathMLParser` has already been *compiled* to a `.class` file (in ./de/...) ? I don't think the scala-runner will do that on the fly.

Comment: This one worked: scala -classpath . MathML2LaTeX.scala Thanks! Btw, that dot, it refers to all subfolders from where I call scala?

Comment: technically, it just refers to the current directory, but java looks in sub-directories according to package-name.